Why is 'cargo flamegraph' running about 45x faster than cargo run (after cargo build --release)?
Until this morning, 'cargo flamegraph' was a bit slower than 'cargo run' after 'cargo build --release'.
I made a small change, swapping out:
std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

with:
rustc_hash::{FxHashMap, FxHashSet};

But, I can't think why this (or anything really) could possibly cause 'cargo flamegraph' to suddenly and dramatically outperform 'cargo run'.

If whatever you're benchmarking is heavy on hash table usage, this "small change" could indeed be massively impactful! Also, have you simply tried switching it back and see if the difference goes away?

@SebastianRedl It does in fact make heavy usage of the hash table, so I'm not surprised by the speedup, but I am surprised that I only see the speedup when using flamegraph.

cargo run will build in debug mode and run that.
If you want to run release, either use the artifact target/release/project_name[.exe], or execute cargo run --release.
